# Different Sub-Menu under each top level menu (main menu)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a Main menu with some links, clicking on each of which will brings the corresponding submenu.
For example the main menu will have links: Link1, Link2, link3.

Link1 will be active by default and the submenus will be  link1a, link1b, link1c.

On clicking link2, the submenu should change to link2a, link2b, link2c.
and similarly for the third link of main menu.

Is there a way to do this using bootstrap, css or js.

Comment: There are many plugins available for this... i recommend http://cssmenumaker.com/

Comment: "Is there a way to do this using bootstrap, css or js." <- Yes it is! @kiran nice tool. :)

Comment: You can do this with bootstrap also..
check out the link..
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=static-navbar-with-dropdown-and-search-form